# How to Identify accessibility in Android Hybrid App?

Tags: appium

I'm working in appium with page object pattern.

```
public class LoginPageObjects {


     @CacheLookup
        @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "")
        public MobileElement mobno;

        @CacheLookup
        @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "")
        public MobileElement verify;
```

Here how should I identify accessibility ?